# Are isomorphisms stable under pullbacks?

Tags: category-theory

In a category which has pullbacks, do isomorphisms necessarily pull back to isomorphisms?

I can certainly prove that retractions pull back to retractions, but I haven't been able to find a proof that isomorphisms also do.

If not, is there a simple counterexample.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, an isomorphism always has a pull-back (no assumption needed on the category) : if $f: X\to Y$ is an isomorphism, and $g:S\to Y$ is any morphism, then 
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S @>{f^{-1}\circ g}>> X\\
@V{Id}VV @V{f}VV \\
S @>{g}>> Y
\end{CD}$$
is clearly a pull-back diagram (the universal property is easy to check).

So by unicity of fiber product, any pull-back of $f$ along $g$ must be an isomorphism.

Comment: That seems to do it. If $P$ is any other object with morphisms $h_1 : P \to X$ and $h_2 : P \to S$ such that $g\circ h_2 = f\circ h_1$ then $h_2$ is the unique morphism $u : P \to S$ such that $h_2 =$ Id$_S\circ u$ and $h_1 = f^{-1}\circ g\circ u$. Thus $S \cong X\times_Y S$. Thanks.

Comment: One question, can we not write $f:X\to X$ as soon as we demand $f$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: Most of the time it won't lead to any serious mistake, but in general it's better to not make implicit identifications, it can play nasty tricks sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma:** Pullbacks of right-invertible morphisms are right-invertible

**Proof:** Suppose $(P, \alpha:P{\rightarrow}A, \beta:P{\rightarrow}B)$ is a pullback for the diagram $\{f:A{\rightarrow}C, g:B{\rightarrow}C\}$ where $g$ is right-invertible. Then since $1_A:A{\rightarrow}A$, $g_r^{-1}{\circ}f:A{\rightarrow}B$ and $f{\circ}1_A=f=1_C{\circ}f=g{\circ}g_r^{-1}{\circ}f$, by the definition of pullbacks we find that there is a unique $\theta:A{\rightarrow}P$ such that
$1_A=\alpha{\circ}\theta$ and $g_r^{-1}{\circ}f={\beta}{\circ}\theta$. The first equation shows that $\alpha$ is right-invertible.

**Theorem:** Pullbacks of isomorphisms are isomorphisms.

**Proof:** Suppose instead that $g$ is an isomorphism. By the definition of pullbacks we know there is a unique $\rho:P{\rightarrow}P$ such that $\alpha{\circ}\rho=\alpha$ and $\beta{\circ}\rho=\beta$. These equations are clearly satisfied by $1_P$ so we get $\rho=1_P$.
Now by the lemma we know that $\alpha$ is right-invertible and that $g^{-1}{\circ}f={\beta}{\circ}\alpha_r^{-1}$, so we get:
$$\alpha{\circ}(\alpha_r^{-1}{\circ}\alpha)=(\alpha{\circ}\alpha_r^{-1}){\circ}\alpha=1_A{\circ}\alpha=\alpha$$ and
$$\beta{\circ}(\alpha_r^{-1}{\circ}\alpha)=(\beta{\circ}\alpha_r^{-1}){\circ}\alpha=g^{-1}{\circ}(f{\circ}\alpha)=(g^{-1}{\circ}g){\circ}\beta=1_B{\circ}\beta=\beta$$ and so we get that $\rho=\alpha_r^{-1}{\circ}\alpha$, and since $\rho$ is unique $\alpha_r^{-1}{\circ}\alpha=1_P$. This means $\alpha$ is left-invertible and we know it's right-invertible as well, so $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: what does your notation mean here: $(P, \alpha: P \to A, ...)$? What are $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: @grisaitis A pullback for a diagram consisting of two morphisms $\{f:A{\rightarrow}C, g:B{\rightarrow}C\}$ with the same codomain $C$, consists of three things: an object $P$, and two morphisms which map $P$ into the domains of $f$ and $g$, I called those morphisms $\alpha:P{\rightarrow}A$ and $\beta:P{\rightarrow}B$. In that case we call $\alpha$ the pullback of $g$ and $\beta$ the pullback of $f$